# File Descriptor Sharing between Parent and forked Children

Tags: c, sockets, unix, network-programming

I am a beginner in network programming..

i follow stevens and implementing UDP server with reliability.

i have a question.

when a child is forked what happens to parent socket fd in child ...? i read that they get inherited that means we have two copies of socket fd in parent and child ?? do we need to close the inherited parent socket fd in child (stevens code doesnt do that)

how does one close parent fds in child (using close () ??) but not the socket on which the client request arrived ( i should keep this open)?

If i am being naive..please excuse me.

Thanks for the help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File descriptors are indeed 'inherited' when forking, but only with respect to what socket they're connected to, and closing the file descriptor will only close the socket if it's the last one associated with that socket (or file, if we're dealing with files).

What you usually do is you establish the socket, and then you fork. In the parent process (the one where fork returned non-zero) you can go ahead and close the file descriptor using `close(fd)`, if you don't you'll eventually run out of file descriptors in the parent process. This is for stream (e.g. TCP) sockets, where you have one server socket listening for connections, and one socket per established connection. However, you're using UDP, so there is in fact only one socket, and if you intend to keep using it in the parent process, you'll need to figure out how to share it between parent and child process. Both can continue using it, but it'll be almost random who reads what, and in what order stuff is sent. In this case you usually have some kind of multiplexing process, which receives the packets, and forwards them to the appropriate child (per some other mechanism, such as pipes or other sockets) based on some message content (in TCP, it's the source ip/port and destination ip/port tuple).

As Matt pointed out, using `shutdown` will in fact render the socket unusable (usually unwritable, but you can specify this) for all involved. In TCP, this could trigger the sending of a FIN-packet, effectively initiating the tear-down of the connection, but you're still able to receive data until the remote end acknowledges the FIN.